# In java using PDFBox, how to create visible digital signature with text

Tags: java, digital-signature, pdfbox

[Digital text with text and background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bziU3.jpg)I am trying to digitally sign pdf file using PDFBox  in Java with visible text to appear on page similar to one that gets created when manually created in Acrobat. As shown in the image (one with only snap shot I am looking for and another with details of digital signature too), this example shows signing using image file. How to do that?

[image: Digital signature with text on PDF]

Comment: Do you have any code you can show us?  Any errors you are seeing? Please read through [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to see how to ask good questions on SO.

Comment: Did you look at the CreateVisibleSignature.java example in the source code download?

Comment: I have referred CreateVisibleSignature.java , it uses image and no text related to signer gets printed on page, however, I want to print the text something like in the screen shot I have attached. where acrobat image is in background with watermark effect.

Comment: The n2 layer isn't supported, PDFBox can only do with image or insivible. There is a patch ( https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3198 ) but no example has been provided.

Comment: The issue in the comment how has an example to create a text signature.

Answer (score 14):

This code will be included among the samples in the upcoming 2.0.9 release of PDFBox, and the current update can be found [in the repository](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/CreateVisibleSignature2.java?view=markup). See also the discussion in [PDFBOX-3198](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3198). It is more flexible and can include both text and images, or only one of the two, or vector graphics, whatever you want.

```
/**
 * This is a second example for visual signing a pdf. It doesn't use the "design pattern" influenced
 * PDVisibleSignDesigner, and doesn't create its complex multilevel forms described in the Adobe
 * document
 * <a href="https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PPKAppearances.pdf">Digital
 * Signature Appearances</a>, because this isn't required by the PDF specification. See the
 * discussion in December 2017 in PDFBOX-3198.
 *
 * @author Vakhtang Koroghlishvili
 * @author Tilman Hausherr
 */
public class CreateVisibleSignature2 extends CreateSignatureBase
{
    private SignatureOptions signatureOptions;
    private boolean lateExternalSigning = false;
    private File imageFile;

    /**
     * Initialize the signature creator with a keystore (pkcs12) and pin that
     * should be used for the signature.
     *
     * @param keystore is a pkcs12 keystore.
     * @param pin is the pin for the keystore / private key
     * @throws KeyStoreException if the keystore has not been initialized (loaded)
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException if the algorithm for recovering the key cannot be found
     * @throws UnrecoverableKeyException if the given password is wrong
     * @throws CertificateException if the certificate is not valid as signing time
     * @throws IOException if no certificate could be found
     */
    public CreateVisibleSignature2(KeyStore keystore, char[] pin)
            throws KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, CertificateException
    {
        super(keystore, pin);
    }

    public File getImageFile()
    {
        return imageFile;
    }

    public void setImageFile(File imageFile)
    {
        this.imageFile = imageFile;
    }

    public boolean isLateExternalSigning()
    {
        return lateExternalSigning;
    }

    /**
     * Set late external signing. Enable this if you want to activate the demo code where the
     * signature is kept and added in an extra step without using PDFBox methods. This is disabled
     * by default.
     *
     * @param lateExternalSigning
     */
    public void setLateExternalSigning(boolean lateExternalSigning)
    {
        this.lateExternalSigning = lateExternalSigning;
    }

    /**
     * Sign pdf file and create new file that ends with "_signed.pdf".
     *
     * @param inputFile The source pdf document file.
     * @param signedFile The file to be signed.
     * @param humanRect rectangle from a human viewpoint (coordinates start at top left)
     * @param tsaUrl optional TSA url
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void signPDF(File inputFile, File signedFile, Rectangle2D humanRect, String tsaUrl) throws IOException
    {
        this.signPDF(inputFile, signedFile, humanRect, tsaUrl, null);
    }

    /**
     * Sign pdf file and create new file that ends with "_signed.pdf".
     *
     * @param inputFile The source pdf document file.
     * @param signedFile The file to be signed.
     * @param humanRect rectangle from a human viewpoint (coordinates start at top left)
     * @param tsaUrl optional TSA url
     * @param signatureFieldName optional name of an existing (unsigned) signature field
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void signPDF(File inputFile, File signedFile, Rectangle2D humanRect, String tsaUrl, String signatureFieldName) throws IOException
    {
        if (inputFile == null || !inputFile.exists())
        {
            throw new IOException("Document for signing does not exist");
        }

        setTsaUrl(tsaUrl);

        // creating output document and prepare the IO streams.
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(signedFile);

        try (PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(inputFile))
        {
            int accessPermissions = SigUtils.getMDPPermission(doc);
            if (accessPermissions == 1)
            {
                throw new IllegalStateException("No changes to the document are permitted due to DocMDP transform parameters dictionary");
            }
            // Note that PDFBox has a bug that visual signing on certified files with permission 2
            // doesn't work properly, see PDFBOX-3699. As long as this issue is open, you may want to
            // be careful with such files.

            PDSignature signature = null;
            PDAcroForm acroForm = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
            PDRectangle rect = null;

            // sign a PDF with an existing empty signature, as created by the CreateEmptySignatureForm example.
            if (acroForm != null)
            {
                signature = findExistingSignature(acroForm, signatureFieldName);
                if (signature != null)
                {
                    rect = acroForm.getField(signatureFieldName).getWidgets().get(0).getRectangle();
                }
            }

            if (signature == null)
            {
                // create signature dictionary
                signature = new PDSignature();
            }

            if (rect == null)
            {
                rect = createSignatureRectangle(doc, humanRect);
            }

            // Optional: certify
            // can be done only if version is at least 1.5 and if not already set
            // doing this on a PDF/A-1b file fails validation by Adobe preflight (PDFBOX-3821)
            // PDF/A-1b requires PDF version 1.4 max, so don't increase the version on such files.
            if (doc.getVersion() >= 1.5f && accessPermissions == 0)
            {
                SigUtils.setMDPPermission(doc, signature, 2);
            }

            if (acroForm != null && acroForm.getNeedAppearances())
            {
                // PDFBOX-3738 NeedAppearances true results in visible signature becoming invisible 
                // with Adobe Reader
                if (acroForm.getFields().isEmpty())
                {
                    // we can safely delete it if there are no fields
                    acroForm.getCOSObject().removeItem(COSName.NEED_APPEARANCES);
                    // note that if you've set MDP permissions, the removal of this item
                    // may result in Adobe Reader claiming that the document has been changed.
                    // and/or that field content won't be displayed properly.
                    // ==> decide what you prefer and adjust your code accordingly.
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("/NeedAppearances is set, signature may be ignored by Adobe Reader");
                }
            }

            // default filter
            signature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE);

            // subfilter for basic and PAdES Part 2 signatures
            signature.setSubFilter(PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);

            signature.setName("Name");
            signature.setLocation("Location");
            signature.setReason("Reason");

            // the signing date, needed for valid signature
            signature.setSignDate(Calendar.getInstance());

            // do not set SignatureInterface instance, if external signing used
            SignatureInterface signatureInterface = isExternalSigning() ? null : this;

            // register signature dictionary and sign interface
            signatureOptions = new SignatureOptions();
            signatureOptions.setVisualSignature(createVisualSignatureTemplate(doc, 0, rect));
            signatureOptions.setPage(0);
            doc.addSignature(signature, signatureInterface, signatureOptions);

            if (isExternalSigning())
            {
                System.out.println("Signing externally " + signedFile.getName());
                ExternalSigningSupport externalSigning = doc.saveIncrementalForExternalSigning(fos);
                // invoke external signature service
                byte[] cmsSignature = sign(externalSigning.getContent());

                // Explanation of late external signing (off by default):
                // If you want to add the signature in a separate step, then set an empty byte array
                // and call signature.getByteRange() and remember the offset signature.getByteRange()[1]+1.
                // you can write the ascii hex signature at a later time even if you don't have this
                // PDDocument object anymore, with classic java file random access methods.
                // If you can't remember the offset value from ByteRange because your context has changed,
                // then open the file with PDFBox, find the field with findExistingSignature() or
                // PODDocument.getLastSignatureDictionary() and get the ByteRange from there.
                // Close the file and then write the signature as explained earlier in this comment.
                if (isLateExternalSigning())
                {
                    // this saves the file with a 0 signature
                    externalSigning.setSignature(new byte[0]);

                    // remember the offset (add 1 because of "<")
                    int offset = signature.getByteRange()[1] + 1;

                    // now write the signature at the correct offset without any PDFBox methods
                    try (RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(signedFile, "rw"))
                    {
                        raf.seek(offset);
                        raf.write(Hex.getBytes(cmsSignature));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // set signature bytes received from the service and save the file
                    externalSigning.setSignature(cmsSignature);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // write incremental (only for signing purpose)
                doc.saveIncremental(fos);
            }
        }

        // Do not close signatureOptions before saving, because some COSStream objects within
        // are transferred to the signed document.
        // Do not allow signatureOptions get out of scope before saving, because then the COSDocument
        // in signature options might by closed by gc, which would close COSStream objects prematurely.
        // See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3743
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(signatureOptions);
    }

    private PDRectangle createSignatureRectangle(PDDocument doc, Rectangle2D humanRect)
    {
        float x = (float) humanRect.getX();
        float y = (float) humanRect.getY();
        float width = (float) humanRect.getWidth();
        float height = (float) humanRect.getHeight();
        PDPage page = doc.getPage(0);
        PDRectangle pageRect = page.getCropBox();
        PDRectangle rect = new PDRectangle();
        // signing should be at the same position regardless of page rotation.
        switch (page.getRotation())
        {
            case 90:
                rect.setLowerLeftY(x);
                rect.setUpperRightY(x + width);
                rect.setLowerLeftX(y);
                rect.setUpperRightX(y + height);
                break;
            case 180:
                rect.setUpperRightX(pageRect.getWidth() - x);
                rect.setLowerLeftX(pageRect.getWidth() - x - width);
                rect.setLowerLeftY(y);
                rect.setUpperRightY(y + height);
                break;
            case 270:
                rect.setLowerLeftY(pageRect.getHeight() - x - width);
                rect.setUpperRightY(pageRect.getHeight() - x);
                rect.setLowerLeftX(pageRect.getWidth() - y - height);
                rect.setUpperRightX(pageRect.getWidth() - y);
                break;
            case 0:
            default:
                rect.setLowerLeftX(x);
                rect.setUpperRightX(x + width);
                rect.setLowerLeftY(pageRect.getHeight() - y - height);
                rect.setUpperRightY(pageRect.getHeight() - y);
                break;
        }
        return rect;
    }

    // create a template PDF document with empty signature and return it as a stream.
    private InputStream createVisualSignatureTemplate(PDDocument srcDoc, int pageNum, PDRectangle rect) throws IOException
    {
        try (PDDocument doc = new PDDocument())
        {
            PDPage page = new PDPage(srcDoc.getPage(pageNum).getMediaBox());
            doc.addPage(page);
            PDAcroForm acroForm = new PDAcroForm(doc);
            doc.getDocumentCatalog().setAcroForm(acroForm);
            PDSignatureField signatureField = new PDSignatureField(acroForm);
            PDAnnotationWidget widget = signatureField.getWidgets().get(0);
            List<PDField> acroFormFields = acroForm.getFields();
            acroForm.setSignaturesExist(true);
            acroForm.setAppendOnly(true);
            acroForm.getCOSObject().setDirect(true);
            acroFormFields.add(signatureField);

            widget.setRectangle(rect);

            // from PDVisualSigBuilder.createHolderForm()
            PDStream stream = new PDStream(doc);
            PDFormXObject form = new PDFormXObject(stream);
            PDResources res = new PDResources();
            form.setResources(res);
            form.setFormType(1);
            PDRectangle bbox = new PDRectangle(rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
            float height = bbox.getHeight();
            Matrix initialScale = null;
            switch (srcDoc.getPage(pageNum).getRotation())
            {
                case 90:
                    form.setMatrix(AffineTransform.getQuadrantRotateInstance(1));
                    initialScale = Matrix.getScaleInstance(bbox.getWidth() / bbox.getHeight(), bbox.getHeight() / bbox.getWidth());
                    height = bbox.getWidth();
                    break;
                case 180:
                    form.setMatrix(AffineTransform.getQuadrantRotateInstance(2)); 
                    break;
                case 270:
                    form.setMatrix(AffineTransform.getQuadrantRotateInstance(3));
                    initialScale = Matrix.getScaleInstance(bbox.getWidth() / bbox.getHeight(), bbox.getHeight() / bbox.getWidth());
                    height = bbox.getWidth();
                    break;
                case 0:
                default:
                    break;
            }
            form.setBBox(bbox);
            PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;

            // from PDVisualSigBuilder.createAppearanceDictionary()
            PDAppearanceDictionary appearance = new PDAppearanceDictionary();
            appearance.getCOSObject().setDirect(true);
            PDAppearanceStream appearanceStream = new PDAppearanceStream(form.getCOSObject());
            appearance.setNormalAppearance(appearanceStream);
            widget.setAppearance(appearance);

            try (PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(doc, appearanceStream))
            {
                // for 90Â° and 270Â° scale ratio of width / height
                // not really sure about this
                // why does scale have no effect when done in the form matrix???
                if (initialScale != null)
                {
                    cs.transform(initialScale);
                }

                // show background (just for debugging, to see the rect size + position)
                cs.setNonStrokingColor(Color.yellow);
                cs.addRect(-5000, -5000, 10000, 10000);
                cs.fill();

                // show background image
                // save and restore graphics if the image is too large and needs to be scaled
                cs.saveGraphicsState();
                cs.transform(Matrix.getScaleInstance(0.25f, 0.25f));
                PDImageXObject img = PDImageXObject.createFromFileByExtension(imageFile, doc);
                cs.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                cs.restoreGraphicsState();

                // show text
                float fontSize = 10;
                float leading = fontSize * 1.5f;
                cs.beginText();
                cs.setFont(font, fontSize);
                cs.setNonStrokingColor(Color.black);
                cs.newLineAtOffset(fontSize, height - leading);
                cs.setLeading(leading);
                cs.showText("(Signature very wide line 1)");
                cs.newLine();
                cs.showText("(Signature very wide line 2)");
                cs.newLine();
                cs.showText("(Signature very wide line 3)");
                cs.endText();
            }

            // no need to set annotations and /P entry

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            doc.save(baos);
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
        }
    }

    // Find an existing signature (assumed to be empty). You will usually not need this.
    private PDSignature findExistingSignature(PDAcroForm acroForm, String sigFieldName)
    {
        PDSignature signature = null;
        PDSignatureField signatureField;
        if (acroForm != null)
        {
            signatureField = (PDSignatureField) acroForm.getField(sigFieldName);
            if (signatureField != null)
            {
                // retrieve signature dictionary
                signature = signatureField.getSignature();
                if (signature == null)
                {
                    signature = new PDSignature();
                    // after solving PDFBOX-3524
                    // signatureField.setValue(signature)
                    // until then:
                    signatureField.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.V, signature);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("The signature field " + sigFieldName + " is already signed.");
                }
            }
        }
        return signature;
    }

    /**
     * Arguments are
     * [0] key store
     * [1] pin
     * [2] document that will be signed
     * [3] image of visible signature
     *
     * @param args
     * @throws java.security.KeyStoreException
     * @throws java.security.cert.CertificateException
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     * @throws java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException
     * @throws java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws KeyStoreException, CertificateException,
            IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnrecoverableKeyException
    {
        // generate with
        // keytool -storepass 123456 -storetype PKCS12 -keystore file.p12 -genkey -alias client -keyalg RSA
        if (args.length < 4)
        {
            usage();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String tsaUrl = null;
        // External signing is needed if you are using an external signing service, e.g. to sign
        // several files at once.
        boolean externalSig = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
        {
            if (args[i].equals("-tsa"))
            {
                i++;
                if (i >= args.length)
                {
                    usage();
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                tsaUrl = args[i];
            }
            if (args[i].equals("-e"))
            {
                externalSig = true;
            }
        }

        File ksFile = new File(args[0]);
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        char[] pin = args[1].toCharArray();
        keystore.load(new FileInputStream(ksFile), pin);

        File documentFile = new File(args[2]);

        CreateVisibleSignature2 signing = new CreateVisibleSignature2(keystore, pin.clone());

        signing.setImageFile(new File(args[3]));

        File signedDocumentFile;
        String name = documentFile.getName();
        String substring = name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf('.'));
        signedDocumentFile = new File(documentFile.getParent(), substring + "_signed.pdf");

        signing.setExternalSigning(externalSig);

        // Set the signature rectangle
        // Although PDF coordinates start from the bottom, humans start from the top.
        // So a human would want to position a signature (x,y) units from the
        // top left of the displayed page, and the field has a horizontal width and a vertical height
        // regardless of page rotation.
        Rectangle2D humanRect = new Rectangle2D.Float(100, 200, 150, 50);

        signing.signPDF(documentFile, signedDocumentFile, humanRect, tsaUrl, "Signature1");
    }

    /**
     * This will print the usage for this program.
     */
    private static void usage()
    {
        System.err.println("Usage: java " + CreateVisibleSignature2.class.getName()
                + " <pkcs12-keystore-file> <pin> <input-pdf> <sign-image>\n" + "" +
                           "options:\n" +
                           "  -tsa <url>    sign timestamp using the given TSA server\n"+
                           "  -e            sign using external signature creation scenario");
    }

}
```

Comment: Much better than the earlier examples. I merely still wonder whether it would be that difficult to allow the user to create a `PDAppearanceStream` in the *current* document, the document to be signed, and use that as signature appearance. It probably is a nice feature to be able to import a signature appearance from another document but *having to* go that way seems somewhat burdensome, in particular if you would like to share resources already present in the document or if you want to include some tagging information...

Comment: @mkl Yes I am aware of that. I don't like it either. I hate any complexity. But for now, I prefer to wait for some feedback on this code (which hopefully remove complexity) before I make breaking changes in addSignature() or add a new method e.g. addDirectSignature().

Comment: Assuming this landed in PDFBox v2.0.9+,what is the fully qualified class name?

Comment: `org.apache.pdfbox.examples.signature.CreateVisibleSignature2`. It is not in the pdfbox jar, it is in the source code download.

Comment: With this code, I'm able to generate visible digital sign but i want to set z-index css to digitally signed content as it looks like it's the background and another text is the upper side.Can anybody help me ?
I'm using PDFBOX 2.0.21

Comment: There is no CSS in PDF. I'm not sure that what you want is possible at all. Signatures are annotations and these are on top. Some transparency should be possible but that isn't what you asked. You should create a new question.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr is it possible to have signatures without using an image. I mean can we have visible Signature just as text?

Comment: @IsmailSahin that is what this answer is about!

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thank for answering me, but you are using signing.setImageFile(new File(args[3])); isn't this an image?

Comment: @IsmailSahin yes, but you're free to remove that code and you'll still have the text. Yeah, maybe I should improve the code in the repository so that it can get skipped.

Comment: Done and I've added a link to the repository.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it.

Comment: Where can I find `CreateSignatureBase` ?

Comment: In the examples subproject of the source code download.

Answer (score 0):

Call method `addSignatureInDoc(path,password1,password2)`.

SignatureInterface  is used to Create Digital Signature

```java
public class AddDigitalSignatureInPdf implements SignatureInterface {

    private static BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();

    private PrivateKey privKey;

    private Certificate[] cert;
    
    static PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;

    static //PFX File - 
            String pfxPath = PdfGenerator.pfxpath;
            static String digSignImg = PdfGenerator.strDigSignImage;

    public AddDigitalSignatureInPdf(KeyStore keystore, char[] pin) {
        try {
            Enumeration<String> aliases = keystore.aliases();
            String alias = null;
            if (aliases.hasMoreElements())
                alias = aliases.nextElement();
            else
                throw new RuntimeException("Could not find Key");
            privKey = (PrivateKey) keystore.getKey(alias, pin);
            cert = keystore.getCertificateChain(alias);
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //InBuild Method------------------------------------------------
    public byte[] sign(InputStream content) throws IOException {
        Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
        System.out.println("Sign----");
        CMSProcessableInputStream input = new CMSProcessableInputStream(content);
        CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
        // CertificateChain
        List<Certificate> certList = Arrays.asList(cert);

        CertStore certStore = null;
        try {
            certStore = CertStore.getInstance("Collection",
                    new CollectionCertStoreParameters(certList), provider);
            gen.addSigner(privKey, (X509Certificate) certList.get(0),
                    CMSSignedGenerator.DIGEST_SHA256);
            gen.addCertificatesAndCRLs(certStore);
            CMSSignedData signedData = gen.generate((CMSProcessable) input, false, "BC");
            
            return signedData.getEncoded();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // should be handled
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Problem while preparing signature");
    }

        public static void addSignatureInDoc( String pdfPath, String own_pass1, String own_pass2, String key_password) throws KeyStoreException,
                NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException,
                FileNotFoundException, IOException,
                SignatureException, Exception {
            File document = new File(pdfPath);
            PDDocument pdDocument = null;
            if(own_pass1==null) {
                pdDocument = PDDocument.load(document,own_pass2);
            }else {
                pdDocument = PDDocument.load(document,own_pass1);
            }
            
            pdDocument.isAllSecurityToBeRemoved();
    
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pdfPath);
            addSignature(pdDocument, key_password);
            pdDocument.saveIncremental(fos);
            
            PdfBoxHeader encrypt  = new PdfBoxHeader();
            //Make File Password protected ------------------------------------
            encrypt.encyyptPdfFile(pdDocument, own_pass1,  own_pass2);
            pdDocument.close();
        }


    private static PDRectangle createSignatureRectangle(PDDocument doc, Rectangle2D humanRect) {

        float x = (float) humanRect.getX();
        float y = (float) humanRect.getY();
        float width = (float) humanRect.getWidth();
        float height = (float) humanRect.getHeight();
        PDPage page = doc.getPage(doc.getNumberOfPages()-1);
        PDRectangle pageRect = page.getCropBox();
        PDRectangle rect = new PDRectangle();

        // Signature image should be at the same position regardless of page rotation.
        // Coordinates start from bottom left.
        switch (page.getRotation()) {
            case 90:
                rect.setLowerLeftX(pageRect.getWidth() - y - height);
                rect.setUpperRightX(pageRect.getWidth() - y);
                rect.setLowerLeftY(x);
                rect.setUpperRightY(x + width);
                break;
            case 180:
                rect.setLowerLeftX(pageRect.getWidth() - x - width);
                rect.setUpperRightX(pageRect.getWidth() - x);
                rect.setLowerLeftY(pageRect.getHeight() - y - height);
                rect.setUpperRightY(pageRect.getHeight() - y);
                break;
            case 270:
                rect.setLowerLeftX(y);
                rect.setUpperRightX(y + height);
                rect.setLowerLeftY(pageRect.getHeight() - x - width);
                rect.setUpperRightY(pageRect.getHeight() - x);
                break;
            case 0:
            default:
                rect.setLowerLeftX(x);
                rect.setUpperRightX(x + width);
                rect.setLowerLeftY(y);
                rect.setUpperRightY(y + height);
                break;
        }

        return rect;
    }

    public static void  addSignature(PDDocument  pdDocument,  String pwd)  throws Exception{

        File securityFileKeyPair = new File(pfxPath);
        InputStream cerFileStream = new FileInputStream(securityFileKeyPair);
        
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", provider);
        char[] pin = pwd.toCharArray();
        keystore.load(cerFileStream, pin);
        AddDigitalSignatureInPdf signing = new AddDigitalSignatureInPdf(keystore, pin.clone());

        //create signature dictionary
        PDSignature signature = new PDSignature();
        signature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE); // default filter
        signature.setSubFilter(PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
        signature.setReason("Signed Digitally");
        signature.setLocation("NSDL , 4th Floor, Trade World A Wing, \n Kamala Mills Compound, Senapati Bapat Marg, \n Lower Parel, Mumbai  400 013");

        byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(cerFileStream);
        signature.setContents(bytes);

          // the signing date, needed for valid signature
            signature.setSignDate(Calendar.getInstance());
            SignatureOptions options = new SignatureOptions();
            options.setPreferredSignatureSize(600);
            options.setPreferredSignatureSize(20000);

            // The code for visible signature starts here
            // Page numbering starts from zero.
            int pageNum = pdDocument.getNumberOfPages()-1; 
            options.setPage(pageNum);

            //Set Rectangle  -----------------------------------------
            Rectangle2D humanRect = new Rectangle2D.Float(
                100,
                600,
                230,
                150
            );

            PDRectangle rect = createSignatureRectangle(pdDocument, humanRect);
            
            //Set Template ----------------------------
            options.setVisualSignature(createVisualSignatureTemplate(pdDocument,pageNum, rect,digSignImg,signature ));
            pdDocument.addSignature(signature, signing, options);
    }

     // Create a template PDF document with empty signature and return it as a stream.
    private static InputStream createVisualSignatureTemplate( PDDocument srcDoc,int pageNum,PDRectangle rect, String digSignImg, PDSignature signature) throws IOException {
        try (PDDocument doc = new PDDocument()) {
            PDPage page = new PDPage(srcDoc.getPage(pageNum).getMediaBox());
            doc.addPage(page);
 
            PDAcroForm acroForm = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
            if (acroForm == null) {
                acroForm = new PDAcroForm(doc);
                doc.getDocumentCatalog().setAcroForm(acroForm);
            }
            acroForm.getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
            
            doc.getDocumentCatalog().setAcroForm(acroForm);
            PDSignatureField signatureField = new PDSignatureField(acroForm);
            signatureField.setValue(signature);

            PDAnnotationWidget widget = signatureField.getWidgets().get(0);
            List<PDField> acroFormFields = acroForm.getFields();
            acroForm.setSignaturesExist(true);
            acroForm.setAppendOnly(true);
            acroForm.getCOSObject().setDirect(true);
            acroForm.getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdated(true);

            acroFormFields.add(signatureField);

            widget.setRectangle(rect);

            // from PDVisualSigBuilder.createHolderForm()
            PDStream stream = new PDStream(doc);
            PDFormXObject form = new PDFormXObject(stream);
            PDResources res = new PDResources();
            form.setResources(res);
            form.setFormType(1);
            PDRectangle bbox = new PDRectangle(rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
            Matrix initialScale = null;
            int pageRotation = srcDoc.getPage(0).getRotation();
            switch (pageRotation) {
                case 90:
                    form.setMatrix(AffineTransform.getQuadrantRotateInstance(1));
                    initialScale = Matrix.getScaleInstance(bbox.getWidth() / bbox.getHeight(), bbox.getHeight() / bbox.getWidth());
                    break;
                case 180:
                    form.setMatrix(AffineTransform.getQuadrantRotateInstance(2));
                    break;
                case 270:
                    form.setMatrix(AffineTransform.getQuadrantRotateInstance(3));
                    initialScale = Matrix.getScaleInstance(bbox.getWidth() / bbox.getHeight(), bbox.getHeight() / bbox.getWidth());
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            form.setBBox(bbox);

            // From PDVisualSigBuilder.createAppearanceDictionary()
            PDAppearanceDictionary appearance = new PDAppearanceDictionary();
            appearance.getCOSObject().setDirect(true);
            PDAppearanceStream appearanceStream = new PDAppearanceStream(form.getCOSObject());
            appearance.setNormalAppearance(appearanceStream);
            widget.setAppearance(appearance);

            try (PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(doc, appearanceStream)) {
                if (initialScale != null) {
                    cs.transform(initialScale);
                }                  
                    cs.saveGraphicsState();
                    PDImageXObject img = PDImageXObject.createFromFile(digSignImg, doc);
                    float imageWidth = bbox.getWidth();
                    float imageHeight = bbox.getHeight();
                    if (pageRotation == 90 || pageRotation == 270) {
                        imageWidth = bbox.getHeight();
                        imageHeight = bbox.getWidth();
                    }
                    //Set Image  ------------------------------------------- 
                    cs.drawImage(img, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);


                    String name = "Name of Company"; // Replace with the actual name
                    String Location = "2024-01-06"; // Replace with the current date or appropriate date format

                    float textStartX = 10; // Adjust X-coordinate
                    float textStartY = 110; // Adjust Y-coordinate

                    
                    //Name  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    cs.beginText();
                    cs.newLineAtOffset(textStartX, textStartY); // Set the text starting position
                    cs.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD, 8); // Set font again for the date
                    cs.showText("Digitally Signed by: " + name); // Display name
                    textStartY -= 10; 
                    cs.newLineAtOffset(0, -10); 
                    cs.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD, 8); // Set font again for the date
                    cs.showText("DEPOSITORY"); // Display date

                    // Date ----------------------------------------
                    textStartY -= 12; // Adjust the Y-coordinate to create space between name and date
                    cs.newLineAtOffset(0, -10); // Move cursor to simulate a newline
                    Calendar currentdate = Calendar.getInstance();
                    String strdate = null;
                    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss");
                    strdate = formatter.format(currentdate.getTime());
                    cs.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD, 8); // Set font again for the date
                    cs.showText("Date: " +strdate); // Display date

                    //Location --------------------------------------------
                    textStartY -= 10; 
                    cs.newLineAtOffset(0, -10); 
                    cs.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD, 8); 
                    cs.showText("Reason  : " + signature.getReason()); 

                    textStartY -= 10;
                    cs.newLineAtOffset(0, -10); 
                    Location = "Location Name";
                    cs.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD, 8);
                    cs.showText("Location : " + Location);
                    
                    textStartY -= 10; 
                    cs.newLineAtOffset(0, -10); 
                    Location = "Location  1";
                    cs.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD, 8); 
                    cs.showText(Location);
                    
                    textStartY -= 10; 
                    cs.newLineAtOffset(0, -10); 
                    Location = "Mumbai  400 013";
                    cs.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD, 8); 
                    cs.showText( Location); 
                    
                    cs.endText();;
            }

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            doc.save(baos);
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
        }
    }
}

class CMSProcessableInputStream implements CMSProcessable {

    InputStream in;

    public CMSProcessableInputStream(InputStream is) {
        in = is;
    }

    public Object getContent() {
        return null;
    }

    public void write(OutputStream out) throws IOException, CMSException {
        // read the content only one time
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
        
        
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```