# Adding digital signature to pdf at specific position

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfbox, digital-signature

I have a Spring boot project that requires adding digital signature to pdf file like this:
[image]

Also merge it to the pdf content and display like this:[image]

But I have no idea how to add/merge this into the pdf file at a specific position (like the picture 2). I hear that IText or PDFBox could do that but don't know how to do. Please help me!

Comment: For PDFBox, see the CreateVisibleSignature2.java example, also here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48232829/535646

Comment: Great to hear that! Consider deleting your question and upvoting that answer :-)

Comment: Already upvoted but I would like to keep this post :)

Comment: Is this a web application? What is signature source? Is it USB Token or Smartcard connected to client's browser?

Comment: @Bharat Vasant, It's web app, but related to backend (spring boot). The signature source I still consider (maybe let's backend create and store at server side from the info users provide, since the users are not quite good at technical)

Comment: Well, if it's signature of single authority on all documents, and Certifying Authority in your country issues Digital Signature as PFX, you may store pfx on server (securely) and use it on server. If signature is to be fetched from USB token connected to browser, you may need [Browser Extension](https://web.signer.digital/)

Comment: @Bharat Vasant for now we will create public key, private key and self-signed certificate and store all into .p12 file at backend side